# How to prevent QComboBox from displaying unnecessary scrollbar

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

The code below, which is based on an example from zetcode.com, creates a single combo box. There are several issues with the resulting dialog, but the following are especially annoying:

1. PyQt displays a vertical scrollbar for the combo box, although there is plenty of space to display the entire list of options without a scrollbar.
2. I've tried to move the combo box to a position near the upper-left corner of the window, but this isn't working.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QComboBox, QApplication

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.setFixedHeight(500)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        self.lbl = QLabel('Animals', self)
        self.lbl.setStyleSheet('font-size:11pt')

        combo = QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItem('bear')
        combo.addItem('cat')
        combo.addItem('dog')
        combo.addItem('dolphin')
        combo.addItem('elephant')
        combo.addItem('fish')
        combo.addItem('frog')
        combo.addItem('horse')
        combo.addItem('rabbit')
        combo.addItem('rat')
        combo.addItem('shark')
        combo.addItem('snake')
        combo.addItem('tiger')
        combo.addItem('whale')

        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        hbox.addWidget(combo)
        hbox.setSpacing(20)

        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        combo.move(20, 60)
        self.setWindowTitle('QComboBox')
        self.show()

    def onActivated(self, text):

        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could show an image that shows what you indicate in (1) and another of what you want to obtain in that case

Comment: Here's an image showing what I'm currently getting.  Note the wasted space (top half of the window) and the vertical scrollbar.  I don't have an easy way to generate an image showing what I'd like to see, so have to fall back on description: I'd like to see the entire list of animals, with no vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Since I can't insert an image here, I've posted an image at https://ibb.co/xgyMDJF

Comment: pyqt automatically adds the scrollbar if there are more than 10 items in a combobox, try using `combo.setMaxVisibleItems(14)` to increase that limit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two wrong assumptions in the question.

1. the list of a QComboBox is a *popup* widget, it doesn't care (nor it should) about the available space the combobox might have: consider it as much as a context menu, which just pops out *over* the window, possibly going outside its boundaries if it requires more space (and that's just because those boundaries are meaningless to the menu);
2. the combo has been added to a layout manager, which takes care about resizing and positioning its (*managed*) child widgets, and that's why you cannot manually "move" them: the layout already sets the geometries automatically on its own everytime the widget is resized (which also happen when it's shown the first time), so any attempt to use `move()`, `resize()` or `setGeometry()` is completely useless;

When adding a widget to a layout, the default behavior is to make it occupy as much space as possible; since a QComboBox is one of those widgets that have a fixed size, the result is that it's actually centered (vertically and horizontally) in the space the layout is "assigning" to it, and this is clearly visible in your case because you set a fixed size for the container widget that is much bigger than what its contents would need.

There are two ways to align those widgets on top:

- add the `alignment` arguments to `addWidget`:

  ```
      hbox.addWidget(combo, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
      hbox.addWidget(self.lbl, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
  ```

  note that this won't give you good results in your case, because the label and the combo box have different heights, so the label might look "higher" than the combo;
- use a QVBoxLayout layout as main layout for the widget, add the horizontal layout to it and then add a *stretch* after that (a *stretch* on a box layout is a "spacer" that tries to occupy as much space as possible)

  ```
      # ...
      mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
      mainLayout.addLayout(hbox)
      mainLayout.addStretch()
      self.setLayout(mainLayout)
  ```

<sub>PS: if you need to add lots of (string only) elements to a QComboBox, use [`addItems()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItems) instead of individually adding each of them.</sub>

Comment: This answer is very helpful, but does not explain why I'm getting the vertical scrollbar.